# Nested dictionary --> reformed dictionary --> multi-index dataframe --> stacking. Result not as desired, as values are being separated

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
test_dict = {'header1_1': {'header2_1': {'header3_1': {'header4_1': ['322.5', 330.0, -0.28],
    'header4_2': ['322.5', 332.5, -0.26]},
   'header3_2': {'header4_1': ['285.0', 277.5, -0.09],
    'header4_2': ['287.5', 277.5, -0.12]}},
  'header2_2': {'header3_1': {'header4_1': ['345.0', 357.5, -0.14],
    'header4_2': ['345.0', 362.5, -0.14]},
   'header3_2': {'header4_1': ['257.5', 245.0, -0.1],
    'header4_2': ['257.5', 240.0, -0.08]}}}}
```

There are 4 levels of headers, and each level can have multiple values, e.g., header1_1, header1_2. And once you specify a combination of these headers, you have a list containing 3 values.

I want to get this into a dataframe, so I create a reformed dictionary:

```
reformed_dict = {}
for outerKey, innerDict in test_dict.items():
    for innerKey, innerDict2 in innerDict.items():
        for innerKey2, innerDict3 in innerDict2.items():
            for innerKey3, values in innerDict3.items():
                reformed_dict[(outerKey,
                        innerKey, innerKey2, innerKey3)] = values
  
reformed_dict
```

And the reformed dictionary looks like:
{('header1_1', 'header2_1', 'header3_1', 'header4_1'): ['322.5', 330.0, -0.28],
('header1_1', 'header2_1', 'header3_1', 'header4_2'): ['322.5', 332.5, -0.26],
('header1_1', 'header2_1', 'header3_2', 'header4_1'): ['285.0', 277.5, -0.09],
('header1_1', 'header2_1', 'header3_2', 'header4_2'): ['287.5', 277.5, -0.12],
('header1_1', 'header2_2', 'header3_1', 'header4_1'): ['345.0', 357.5, -0.14],
('header1_1', 'header2_2', 'header3_1', 'header4_2'): ['345.0', 362.5, -0.14],
('header1_1', 'header2_2', 'header3_2', 'header4_1'): ['257.5', 245.0, -0.1],
('header1_1', 'header2_2', 'header3_2', 'header4_2'): ['257.5', 240.0, -0.08]}

Throw that into a dataframe:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(reformed_dict)
```

And it looks like:
header1_1
header2_1   header2_2
header3_1   header3_2   header3_1   header3_2
header4_1   header4_2   header4_1   header4_2   header4_1   header4_2   header4_1   header4_2
0   322.5   322.5   285.0   287.5   345.0   345.0   257.5   257.5
1   330.0   332.5   277.5   277.5   357.5   362.5   245.0   240.0
2   -0.28   -0.26   -0.09   -0.12   -0.14   -0.14   -0.1    -0.08

What I'd like to do is have all the column headers be row headers, and have 3 columns for each combination of headers and I'd name the columns Val1, Val2, Val3.

So I use df.stack() to push the column headers into the rows:

```
df_1 = df.stack(level=0)
df_2 = df_1.stack(level=0)
df_3 = df_2.stack(level=0)
df_4 = df_3.stack(level=0)
print(df_4)
```

The result is:
header1_1  header2_1  header3_1  header4_1    322.5
header4_2    322.5
header3_2  header4_1    285.0
header4_2    287.5
header2_2  header3_1  header4_1    345.0
header4_2    345.0
header3_2  header4_1    257.5
header4_2    257.5
1  header1_1  header2_1  header3_1  header4_1    330.0
header4_2    332.5
header3_2  header4_1    277.5
header4_2    277.5
header2_2  header3_1  header4_1    357.5
header4_2    362.5
header3_2  header4_1    245.0
header4_2    240.0
2  header1_1  header2_1  header3_1  header4_1    -0.28
header4_2    -0.26
header3_2  header4_1    -0.09
header4_2    -0.12
header2_2  header3_1  header4_1    -0.14
header4_2    -0.14
header3_2  header4_1     -0.1
header4_2    -0.08

This isn't the layout I was looking for, as I want the 3 values in each list to be on the same row, similar to how they are in the reformed dictionary.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please post what your expected output looks like for given sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html).

Convert keys of dict to index and use dict values as data:

```py
keys = reformed_dict.keys()
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(keys, names=["header1", "header2", "header3", "header4"])

values = [reformed_dict[k] for k in keys]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=index)
```

Output:

```
header1   header2   header3   header4                      
header1_1 header2_1 header3_1 header4_1  322.5  330.0 -0.28
                              header4_2  322.5  332.5 -0.26
                    header3_2 header4_1  285.0  277.5 -0.09
                              header4_2  287.5  277.5 -0.12
          header2_2 header3_1 header4_1  345.0  357.5 -0.14
                              header4_2  345.0  362.5 -0.14
                    header3_2 header4_1  257.5  245.0 -0.10
                              header4_2  257.5  240.0 -0.08
```

If you want index to be columns:

```py
df = df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     header1    header2    header3    header4      0      1     2
0  header1_1  header2_1  header3_1  header4_1  322.5  330.0 -0.28
1  header1_1  header2_1  header3_1  header4_2  322.5  332.5 -0.26
2  header1_1  header2_1  header3_2  header4_1  285.0  277.5 -0.09
3  header1_1  header2_1  header3_2  header4_2  287.5  277.5 -0.12
4  header1_1  header2_2  header3_1  header4_1  345.0  357.5 -0.14
5  header1_1  header2_2  header3_1  header4_2  345.0  362.5 -0.14
6  header1_1  header2_2  header3_2  header4_1  257.5  245.0 -0.10
7  header1_1  header2_2  header3_2  header4_2  257.5  240.0 -0.08
```

Comment: The purpose of pandas MultiIndex is not to create columns out of list of tuples, so suggesting it as a solution to the problem in question not really appropriate. By the way you can just use `values = reformed_dict.values()` instead of `values = [reformed_dict[k] for k in keys]` which does the same but is a unnecessary waste of computation time.

Comment: OP has not clearly mentioned his expected output. From his nested dict, it looks like he wants multi-index. Hence the solution. The index to columns is an extension.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right. Haven't seen it that way. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @jub, did this solve your problem?

Comment: @AzharKhan with the resulting dataframe created by your solution, how would I rename the 3 columns of data? I tried ``df.columns = ['col 1', 'col 2' 'col 3']`` and got error:  ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements

Comment: `df = df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'})`

Comment: @AzharKhan that rename didn't work for me. Not enough space in comment field to flesh it out, so I created a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74564252/manipulating-multiindex-pandas-dataframe-and-writing-to-google-sheets

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
test_dict = \
{'header1_1': {'header2_1': {'header3_1': {'header4_1': ['322.5', 330.0, -0.28],
                                           'header4_2': ['322.5', 332.5, -0.26]},
                             'header3_2': {'header4_1': ['285.0', 277.5, -0.09],
                                           'header4_2': ['287.5', 277.5, -0.12]}},
               'header2_2': {'header3_1': {'header4_1': ['345.0', 357.5, -0.14],
                                           'header4_2': ['345.0', 362.5, -0.14]},
                             'header3_2': {'header4_1': ['257.5', 245.0, -0.10],
                                           'header4_2': ['257.5', 240.0, -0.08]}}}}
#from pprint import pprint
#pprint(test_dict)

from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
dct_N = defaultdict(list)
total_rows = 0
def fillDataFrameDict(dct, level=0):
    global dct_N, total_rows
    for key, value in dct.items():
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            dct_N[f'headerNo_{level+1}'].append(key)
            total_rows += 1 
            dct_N['body'].append(value)
            for key_N, value_N in dct_N.items():
                dct_N[key_N] = value_N + (total_rows-len(value_N))*[value_N[-1]]
        else: 
            dct_N[f'headerNo_{level+1}'].append(key)
            fillDataFrameDict(value, level+1)

fillDataFrameDict(test_dict)
df = pd.DataFrame(dct_N)
print(df)
```

which gives:

```
  headerNo_1 headerNo_2 headerNo_3 headerNo_4                   body
0  header1_1  header2_1  header3_1  header4_1  [322.5, 330.0, -0.28]
1  header1_1  header2_1  header3_1  header4_2  [322.5, 332.5, -0.26]
2  header1_1  header2_1  header3_2  header4_1  [285.0, 277.5, -0.09]
3  header1_1  header2_1  header3_2  header4_2  [287.5, 277.5, -0.12]
4  header1_1  header2_2  header3_1  header4_1  [345.0, 357.5, -0.14]
5  header1_1  header2_2  header3_1  header4_2  [345.0, 362.5, -0.14]
6  header1_1  header2_2  header3_2  header4_1   [257.5, 245.0, -0.1]
7  header1_1  header2_2  header3_2  header4_2  [257.5, 240.0, -0.08]
```

When dealing with deep nested lists or dictionaries usage of recursion for traversing the nested branches is a perfect case where usage of recursion makes sense.

Down the path to the `body` elements the recursive function above tests the type of dictionary values and stops recursive calls when the value is not a dictionary.

Tracking the level and the number of rows during the recursion calls allows to fill up the columns with appropriate values, so there is equal number of row elements in each column for creating a pandas DataFrame.

The `defaultdict(list)` dictionary object provided in the `collections` module (which is part of standard Python installation) creates an empty list as a value and returns it for keys not yet stored in the dictionary. This saves some lines of code necessary to create the first `key:value` entry in a dictionary in before populating the list with items.