# MultiIndex pandas dataframe and writing to Google Sheets using gspread-pandas

Tags: python, pandas, gspread

Starting with the following dictionary:

```
test_dict = {'header1_1': {'header2_1': {'header3_1': {'header4_1': ['322.5', 330.0, -0.28],
    'header4_2': ['322.5', 332.5, -0.26]},
   'header3_2': {'header4_1': ['285.0', 277.5, -0.09],
    'header4_2': ['287.5', 277.5, -0.12]}},
  'header2_2': {'header3_1': {'header4_1': ['345.0', 357.5, -0.14],
    'header4_2': ['345.0', 362.5, -0.14]},
   'header3_2': {'header4_1': ['257.5', 245.0, -0.1],
    'header4_2': ['257.5', 240.0, -0.08]}}}}
```

I want the headers in the index, so I reform the dictionary:

```
reformed_dict = {}
for outerKey, innerDict in test_dict.items():
    for innerKey, innerDict2 in innerDict.items():
        for innerKey2, innerDict3 in innerDict2.items():
            for innerKey3, values in innerDict3.items():
                reformed_dict[(outerKey,
                        innerKey, innerKey2, innerKey3)] = values
```

And assign column names to the headers:

```
keys = reformed_dict.keys()
values = reformed_dict.values()
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(keys, names=["H1", "H2", "H3", "H4"])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=index)
```

That gets to a dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

**Issue #1** [*** this has been answered by @AzharKhan, so feel free to skip ahead to Issue #2 ***]:  To assign names to the data columns, I tried:

```
df.columns = ['col 1', 'col 2' 'col 3']
```

and got error: "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements"

Then per a suggestion, I tried:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'0': 'Col1', '1': 'Col2', '2': 'Col3'})
```

This does not generate an error, but the dataframe looks exactly the same as before, with 0, 1, 2 as the data column headers.

How can I assign names to these data columns? I assume 0, 1, 2 are column indices, not column names.

**Issue #2**:  When I write this dataframe to Google Sheets using [gspread-pandas](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
s.open_sheet('test')
Spread.df_to_sheet(s, df, index=True, headers=True, start='A8', replace=False)
```

The result is this:
[image]

What I would like is this:
[image]

This is how the dataframe appears in Jupyter notebook screenshot earlier, so it seems the process of writing to spreadsheet is filling in the empty row headers, which makes the table harder to read at a glance.

How can I get the output to spreadsheet to omit the row headers until they have changed, and thus get the second spreadsheet output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creator of gspread-pandas has added the functionality to merge indexes when writing a dataframe to Google Sheets. It's not yet in general release version of gspread-pandas, but can be found here: https://github.com/aiguofer/gspread-pandas/pull/92

Answer (score 1):

**Issue #1**

Your columns are numbers (not strings). You can see it by:

```py
print(df.columns)

[Out]:
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
```

Use numbers in `df.rename()` as follows:

```py
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'Col1', 1: 'Col2', 2: 'Col3'})
print(df.columns)
print(df)

[Out]:
Index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], dtype='object')

                                          Col1   Col2  Col3
H1        H2        H3        H4                           
header1_1 header2_1 header3_1 header4_1  322.5  330.0 -0.28
                              header4_2  322.5  332.5 -0.26
                    header3_2 header4_1  285.0  277.5 -0.09
                              header4_2  287.5  277.5 -0.12
          header2_2 header3_1 header4_1  345.0  357.5 -0.14
                              header4_2  345.0  362.5 -0.14
                    header3_2 header4_1  257.5  245.0 -0.10
                              header4_2  257.5  240.0 -0.08
```

Or if you want to generalise it rather than hard coding then use:

```py
df = df.rename(columns={i:f"Col{i+1}" for i in df.columns})
```

I am not sure about your issue #2. You may want to carve it out into a separate question to get attention.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was trying to rename column headers as if they were strings. But they were an index (numbers) assigned by pandas since I had previously moved all the data column headers into the rows. Thanks again @AzharKhan

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer.  The code was alphabetizing after creating the data frame and that was throwing off the index.  I moved alphabetizing before creation of the data frame and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to handle issue #1 by using `pd.json_normalize()`

```
df = pd.json_normalize(test_dict,max_level=3).stack().droplevel(0)
idx = df.index.map(lambda x: tuple(x.split('.'))).rename(['H1','H2','H3','H4'])
df = pd.DataFrame(df.tolist(),index = idx,columns = ['col1','col2','col3'])
```

Output:

```
                                          col1   col2  col3
H1        H2        H3        H4                           
header1_1 header2_1 header3_1 header4_1  322.5  330.0 -0.28
                              header4_2  322.5  332.5 -0.26
                    header3_2 header4_1  285.0  277.5 -0.09
                              header4_2  287.5  277.5 -0.12
          header2_2 header3_1 header4_1  345.0  357.5 -0.14
                              header4_2  345.0  362.5 -0.14
                    header3_2 header4_1  257.5  245.0 -0.10
                              header4_2  257.5  240.0 -0.08
```

Issue #2 is tricky because Jupyter notebook displays the index with the "blank" values, but if you were to do `df.index`, it would show that all the data is actually there. Its just a visual choice used by Jupyter notebooks.

In order to achieve this, you can check for value changes and join newly created df.

```
idx_df = df.index.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)

df = idx_df.where(idx_df.ne(idx_df.shift())).join(df.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: Good point; so a solution probably isn't going to be found via gspread-pandas module as that is faithfully writing the contents of the dataframe to spreadsheet. I'll do some more searching if there's a premade solution for this in pandas. Failing that, maybe adding a numerical index to the dataframe (to keep the rows ordered) and then loop thru rows and brute force deleting the repetitive row headers?

Comment: i made an edit.